# js - Comparison with 0 always returns true?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

I'm just printing a rectangle to the console to get somewhat familiar with JS. I have a nested loop (pseudocode `for i < this.height`, `for j < this.width`). If j is 0 or width - 1, I'd like to print out a `|` for the border:

```js
if (j == this.width - 1 || j == 0)
{ c = '|'; }
```

and then `c` is appended to my output. The comparison to  `0` returns true regardless of the `j` value. My best guess is that it doesn't think that 0 is the type that is, or I've used it in some way that JS thinks it's a wildcard. For reference, my output looks like this:

```
--------
||||||||
||||||||
||||||||
||||||||
||||||||
||||||||
--------
```

The -'s at the top and bottom are specified in the outer loop.

#### Minimal Reproducible Example

Agh, sorry I forgot this. Here's the code for the function:

```js
let obj =
  {'width': 8
  ,'height': 8  
  ,'ascii_display' : function() {
      let output_str = "";
      for (let i = 0; i < this.height; i++) {
        let c = ' ';

        /* inner loop will not override these */
        if (i == 0 || i == this.height - 1) {
          c = '-'; 
        }

        for (let j = 0; j < this.width; j++) {
          if (c == " ") {
            if (j == this.width - 1 || j == 0) {
              c = '|'; 
            }
          }
          output_str += c;
        }
        output_str += "\n";
      }
      console.log(output_str);
      }
  };
  
obj.ascii_display();
```

Comment: @Carcigenicate sorry about forgetting this, and no I do not believe I am ever resetting `c`.

Comment: @CtrlAltF2 Where is the `this` coming from?

Comment: @DominiqueFortin This is a method in a class, I can include the constructor if you need it, but it's just setting `this.width` and `this.height`. In the example output shown, it's 8 and 8.

Comment: A comparison is true only if it is true. Ensure that titles are not misleading, as the hypothesis/claim presented can be trivially checked in the console. Using a debugger to step through the code would have also allowed self-identification of the issue.

Comment: @CtrlAltF2 Sorry for typo

Comment: @CtrlAltF2 What is the desired output?

Comment: @user2864740 Yes, I agree this question is pretty bad. My brain just sort of failed while I was looking at this code. However, I do not think the question title is inaccurate. The comparison returns true because it set c to 0, and that is my problem. I was asking why it returned true, which the answer explains. Why do you think it is misleading?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You change `c` to a pipe, then never change it back to anything else. Also note that above that, you do a `if (c == " ") {` check, but once `c` is a pipe, that check will never be true, so the check below it will never be reached.

You probably want something closer to this:

```
for (let j = 0; j < this.width; j++) {
    if (j == this.width - 1 || j == 0) {
        c = '|';
    } else {
        c = ' ';  // Reset it back after
    }

    . . .    
}
```

Which can be simplified a bit using a conditional expression ("ternary"):

```
for (let j = 0; j < this.width; j++) {
    c = (j == this.width - 1 || j == 0) ? "|" : " ";    
    . . .    

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need first initialize `j`.

eg:

```
for (var j = 0;j < this.width; j++)
```

or

```
var j = 0;
for (;j < this.width;j++)...
```

Comment: This is what the let statement is for. I have written `let j = 0` into the loop.